# Zend multicountry redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework

currently I have an Zend application on default location 
`www.example.com/{controller}/{action}`

but when a user visit from a specific country, how to detect their ip address and redirect them to this countryCode based url
`www.example.com/uk/{controller}/{action}`?

To detect the country from which the user are visiting I have written a helper:

```
require_once '../library/Ipinfo/ip2locationlite.class.php';

class Application_View_Helper_GetLocation extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getLocation()
    {

        $ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
        $ipLite->setKey('APIKEY');

        //Get errors and locations
        $locations = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $errors = $ipLite->getError();

        $country = strtolower($locations['countryName']);

        return "$country";
    }
}
```

The above code will return the country name. If a user is visiting from France how can I rewrite the url so that the url becomes `example.com/france/{controller}/{action}`?

Comment: Why do you assume the country indicates a language preference? The HTTP `Accept-Language` header should be used for that. The country code is useful for country-specific things, like currency and postal code tables.

Comment: Also, it's probably a better idea to not have separate directories for each language. You should be using ccTLDs or return content in the correct language specified by `Accept-Language` while keeping the same URL scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your view helper into a Controller Plugin and redirect.

A controller plugin can execute early in the request dispatch loop, therefore you can intercept a request and redirect to another response before any controller is loaded and rendered. Example below (warning, may contain bugs!)

```
class App_Plugin_DetectCountry extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
        $ipLite->setKey('APIKEY');

        //Get errors and locations
        $locations = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $errors = $ipLite->getError();

        $country = strtolower($locations['countryName']);

        //Check if set country equals detected country
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['country']) || $country !== $_COOKIE['country']) {
            $_COOKIE['country'] = $country;
            $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
            $redirector->gotoUrl($country . '/' . $request->getControllerName() . '/' . $request->getActionName()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming in this example that $country equals the country code. Otherwise you'll need to provide a map of country to country codes to properly construct the redirect URL.

Comment: hi yes i will map a country code to country that i receive from ipinfodb eg if i receive Singapore i wil map it to sg so the url will be example.com/sg/controller/action. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @tripleee's comment about using the HTTP header rather than lookup up their IP which can often result in incorrect values, or force users behind remote proxies into settings they don't want.

Try this controller plugin for redirecting based on the user's Locale as given by their browser:

```
<?php

class Application_Plugin_Language extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        /*
        // if you add "localization.default_locale = "en_US" to your application.ini, uncomment the following
        $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOption('localization'), true);
        $loc = (isset($config->default_locale)) ? $config->default_locale : 'en_US';
        */

        $module = $request->getModuleName();
        if ($module != 'default') return ;

        // You can also check a cookie or session value here to see if you can return from the plugin as well

        $loc = 'en_US';

        Zend_Locale::setDefault($loc);

        try {
            $locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
        } catch (Zend_Locale_Exception $e) {
            $locale = new Zend_Locale($loc);
        }

        $language = $locale->getLanguage();  // e.g. "en", "de", "ru" etc.

        $urlHelper = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url();
        $url = $urlHelper->url(array('module' => $language, 'controller' => 'form', 'action' => 'index'));

        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
        $redirector->gotoUrl($url);
    }
}
```

This plugin will redirect to a module with the language name based on the language set by the user's browser if they are currently requesting the default module.

Note this code does nothing to check if the module you are redirecting to exists or not.  You should check that the language is supported before redirecting.

You could also add a check for a cookie or session value that contains the user's desired language and redirect based on that.

Register the plugin by adding this to `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.language = "Application_Plugin_Language"
```

If you want to redirect based on country and not language, then change `$language = $locale->getLanguage();` to `$region = $locale->getRegion();`

Hope that helps.